# Trying to ID Shrub with star shaped 4 petal white flowers

Tags: identification

A large spreading shrub has flowered for the first time in 8 years. Would love to know its name.

[image: shrub]

Comment: Could you please add a couple of photos? One showing the plant from a distance and the other showing a closeup of the leaves?

Comment: Do you need more than the photo above? I’m happy to take more.

Comment: Yes, we need at least the two photos I asked for in order to make a decent ID. Thanks

Comment: Also, a ruler in the photo, held up behind a flower and leaves, so we can get an idea of the size.

Answer (score 1):

Could well be totally wrong, but it looks vaguely like a single-flowered Philadelphus. Take a look at [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=philadelphus%20single%20flowers&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiU6tS6-v3wAhVB0oUKHTNJAxEQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=philadelphus%20single%20flowers&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzoECCMQJzoCCAA6BAgAEBhQ544BWKusAWDcrQFoAHAAeACAAbcBiAHHCZIBBDEwLjSYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=exm6YNTAIMGklwSzko2IAQ&bih=625&biw=1366&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB725GB725) images.

Comment: They are similar but these have pointed petals and are not notched on the edge.